# How can Spinnaker perform incremental app deployments?

Tags: spinnaker

As part of our pipelines, we currently use a deployment tool that has connectivity to our various instances and we can upload revisions/versions of our app to a central repository, archive them, and redeploy them at any time. Is Spinnaker intended to replace an existing deployment automation tool (there are many on market today) or is more meant for us to create pipelines that call the API of our other tool(s) when actually deploying our code to different servers?

Answer (score 1):

Spinnaker has native support for deployment to supported cloud platforms (AWS, Google, CloudFoundry, and soon Azure).

In those environments, the Spinnaker model is an immutable infrastructure style deployment where new VMs are created to push new software versions.

If that fits your needs, then Spinnaker could replace an existing deployment automation tool.

If that doesn't fit your model, then Spinnaker also supports calling out to an external execution environment as a pipeline stage (currently Jenkins is well supported) where you could implement custom behaviors to integrate to an existing deployment tool.